# Parallel.For To Copy Files

Tags: vb.net

I have an operation that copies files very quickly on my local drive, but when it is run against a server, it can greatly slow down. I had the idea that maybe I could throw it at the Parallel.For. Is it possible? Below is my code.

```
Dim FilesToCopy As HashSet(Of String) = New HashSet(Of String)

    'FilesToCopy holds the files names that will be copied because 
    'the "copy" folder can have hundreds of files, but only a small subset will be copied
For Each Item In FilesToCopy
    FileName = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetName(Item)
    Splitter = Regex.Split(FileName, "_", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    ThisHour = Integer.Parse(Splitter(9).Substring(0, 2)) + 1
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(String.Concat(GrabPath, "\", Item), String.Concat(DropPath, "\", _
    StaticFileName, ThisHour.ToString, ".NETLOSS"), FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, UICancelOption.ThrowException)
    SBuilder.AppendLine(String.Concat(StaticFileName, ThisHour.ToString, ".NETLOSS"))
    LogFile.WriteLine(String.Concat("INFO    The following file (", Item, ") was copied from the ", GrabPath, _
                                    " folder to the ", DropPath, " folder."))
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Parallel.ForEach` is what you want. Since I don't know the VB.NET syntax, I'll give a C# version. I hope it's understandable to you.

Turn this:

```
foreach (var Item in FilesToCopy)
{
    /*do stuff using Item*/
}
```

Into this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(FilesToCopy, Item =>
{
    /*do stuff using Item*/
});
```

You may also want to consider the overload of `ForEach` that takes a third `ParallelOptions` parameter, which you can set the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` property of.

Be aware that whatever "stuff" you're doing in the loop body will need to be threadsafe, meaning (in this context) that it behaves properly if it is being run multiple times for different items concurrently.